# In a Firefox add-on, how to implement injecting a script into an HTML page and sending a message back to the main script?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

My add-on specifically works on a single site.

It injects a contentscript and sends a message to popup(panel in firefox terminology) to display.

**Here is my contentscript:**

```
//this code is same for firefox as well as chrome since it is that which manipulates the page in which it is injected, so I think this is indepent of browser

var table = document.getElementsByClassName("collapse")[0];

var marks = new Array();

 for(var i=0;i<8;i++)
   marks[i] = table.children[0].children[i+1].children[5].innerHTML;

 var total=0;
 for(var i=0;i<8;i++)
   total += Number(marks[i]);

 ------------------------------------------------
//this code is different for firefox
 //code to send the data to popup 
 var fromDOM = total;
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(fromDOM);//what is the equivalent method for sending a message to popup(panel)?
```

**popup.html**

```
//no change , I think would be same with firefox 

<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
  <head>
  <title>Popup page</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="popup.css">
  </head>
  <body>
<div id="output">
  <h1><form name="F1" method="POST">
         TOTAL: <p id="total"></p>
    PERCENTAGE: <p id="percentage"></p>
  </form></h1>
</div>  

  <script src="popup.js">

  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js:**

```
//code to load the contentscript into the page 
chrome.tabs.executeScript({"file": "contentscript.js"});    
//equivalent firefox code??***
-----------------------------------------------------------------
    var total= 0,percentage = 0;

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(response){
total = response;***
//Getting response sent from contentscript, how can I do the same in firefox?
percentage = total/7.25; 


document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
document.getElementById("percentage").innerHTML = percentage.toFixed(2)+" %";


});
```

What are the specific firefox methods for some chrome API's methods mentioned?

I'd be glad if any one could help me out.
Thanks

Comment: coming from chrome you'll probably want addon sdk. for panel: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel and then just emit the show function in your contentScript whenever you get a page load of your site, see page-mod here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod

Comment: Thanks @Noitidart for your answer, that REALLY helped me, gave me a direction. But attaching panel to buttons seems to work only from firefox 30 onwards , so should I use widget or panel. Thanks!

Comment: O wow I didnt know that was from FF30 on I acutally dont use SDK. I do bootstrap so I can do anything and everything. Would you like to see a demo like this?

Comment: I heard that bootstraping is stuff done by advanced developers, and this is my 1st add-on and I'll stick with SDK. Buddy, can I have a template suited to my simple addon.I'd love that!

Comment: I don't have any SDK demos :( We'll have to wait for some other replies. Bootrap takes a bit of understanding yea. I can make this demo for you and keep it in my tutorials found [HERE](https://gist.github.com/search?q=%40Noitidart+addon) but I'm a bit busy with making an addon for the Australis competition. I can write this demo for you when I finish my addon (I should finish it in like 2 weeks)

Comment: Thanks again @Noitidart that's very useful stuff for me, you pointed to. Would you mind me checking some doubts with u abt my addons?

Comment: I'm not sure if I should use panels or widgets, my addon just displays some info and requires no user interaction.Upon a click , it displays info pertaining to that page.So which would u suggest?

Comment: Go with widget which is a button with panel attached. So try widget.

Comment: Thanks @Noitidart I'll go with that. It's nice talking to u. Take care!

Comment: To clarify, the attaching of a button is Australis (UI revamp) onwards, so FF30+, but before that, a widget performs the same function with a panel. Widgets do not work in Australis and were replaced by "buttons"